# Xubuntu 14.04 (and Mint 17.1) will not detect Canon scanner MP237 (MP230 series)

Tags: drivers, canon, scanner, gimp

I just purchased a new multi-function Canon unit ... MP237; copier, printer and scanner.  I have Simple Scan and XSane; along with Gimp, installed.  I can print and copy (as far as I know) just fine. And, I can scan using Gimp.  However, both Simple Scan and XSane "WILL NOT" detect the scanner ("no device available").  So, at this point, I have to use Gimp to effectively use the new Canon unit.  I don't know what, or where, the problem lies.  I suspect the problem is with the two apps ... Simple Scan and XSane.  I have, by the way, manually installed the printer driver, scanner driver and the libtiff4 file.

Comment: What GIMP plug-in does the scanning then? Usually that is XSane, but then XSane should have not problems working by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ScanGear** is a tool that dos not need Gimp (although it can be launched from within Gimp). To run ScanGear separately: `scangearmp`.

[image]

So, you don't need to use Simple Scan or Xsane.

To have ScanGear as a separate launcher/application easily accessible, create a desktop file - more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/725412/47206).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing this or similar problem, here is what I got that helped solve my situation.  Here is what I got from the XSane developer(s) ...

> On Wednesday, 13 May, 2015 03:13 AM, Rolf Bensch wrote:
>   Hi xxxxxxxx,
>
> For your scanner you need to install libsane >= 1.0.24 *or* MP230 series
>   scangearmp from Canon.
>
> To upgrade libsane, you can add my ppa (in a terminal):
>   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Cheers,
>   Rolf

I added to PPA for future updates/upgrades.  This cleared up my problem with both XSane and SimpleScan.

Good Luck.